# htacces file affecting parent directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, osx-server

I have a site set up this way:

The directory structure is:

```
/usr/local/sites/example.com/secure/admin
```

The main host config in apache for example.com:80 points to

```
/usr/local/sites/example.com
```

The https config for example.com:443 points to

```
/usr/local/sites/example.com/secure
```

I have another virtual host using a different domain, let's call it 
example2.com:443 that I use strictly for admin stuff pointing to:

```
/usr/local/sites/example.com/secure/admin
```

I have .htaccess files in both `example.com` and `example.com/secure` with 
some mod_rewrite rules.

There is no .htaccess file in `/usr/local/sites/example.com/secure/admin`

Yet, when I access example2.com to manage the site, the .htaccess files
from the parent directories affect the functionality of the admin pages.

Is it supposed to be that way? Shouldn't apache be applying the 
mod_rewrite rules only in a virtual host's document root?

I tried putting a .htaccess file in `/usr/local/sites/example.com/secure/admin`
with the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine Off
</IfModule>
```

Apache:

```
Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.15 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8r
```

This is on Mac OS X server, if it matters (which is why I've been unable 
to update apache or php). I'm hoping to the hardware to a linux distro 
soon.

Answer (score 1):

You actually want to turn the rewrite engine **on**. Because rules in an htaccess file always supercedes any rules in the parent directory (when `Injerit` isn't used), what you want to do is turn on the rewrite engine and have *no rules* in your htaccess file. This forces it to have precedence over rules in parent directories.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>
```

And because it has precedence and there are no rules, no rewrite stuff gets applied.

Comment: didn't work. Leaving the rewrite engine on and no rules had no effect on the problem. Still, it's weird that a .htaccess file in a directory above the document_root directory affects the site. Theoretically, it shouldn't.

Comment: @JohnnyBravo No, there shouldn't be a way htaccess files outside of the document root get evaluated. Are you *sure* it's those htaccess files? Like, if you remove them, then you access `example2.com:443`, everything works?

Comment: Yes, it is the files in the parent directory. I disabled them temporarily and everything worked. It's driving me nuts. I updated the server to apache 2.2.4 and php 5.3.26 and that didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know the `RewriteOptions Inherit` directive to avoid RewriteRule's override by sub-folder's .htaccess.